# Como trocar o atributo position (css) de uma div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma `div` de `id = 'retangulo'` com `position:absolute;`. Quando a página carrega, esse retângulo vertical só aparece pela metade. Quero que quando a pessoa rolar o site em uma altura que todo o retângulo apareça, ele fique com a `position:fixed;` sempre acompanhando o movimento da tela.

```css
header{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background-color:#423142;
}

div#retangulo{
  width:50px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: green;
  position:absolute;
  top:220px;
  left:100px;
}

footer{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="retangulo">
  {texto exemplo....}
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Exemplificando com o fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pjegfkrz/

Seguindo o exemplo: Como pode se perceber, ao abrir o exemplo, vemos que não estamos vendo completamente a div do retângulo, mas há um momento que rolando pra baixo pode se ver todo o retângulo. Nesse momento, gostaria de que o retângulo ficasse com a `position:fixed;` acompanhando a tela.

Comment: Poderia compartilhar seu código ou prover um Fiddle?

Comment: Você quer que quando o usuário diminuir a tela mude para `position:fixed;` ?

Comment: Isso, quando o usuário rolar para baixo até uma certa altura, a `position` fique `absolute`, mas quando chega nessa altura, troque para `position:fixed;`

Comment: Ainda não entendi o que deseja. Poderia explicar um pouco mais?

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você não saiba o offset (posição no scroll do seu element) primeiro precisamos descobri-la:

```
//detecta scroll na janela
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    var retangulo = $('#retangulo');
    //obtem a posição da div com relação ao scroll
    var posicao = retangulo.offset();

    //define se o scroll atual é maior ou igual a posição da div
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= posicao.top) {
      $("#retangulo").css({"position" : "fixed"});
    }else{
       $("#retangulo").css({"position" : "absolute"});
    }
  });
```

Basicamente cada vez que o usuário der scroll na pagina essa função irá se repetir e verificar se a altura do scroll atual é maior ou igual a do seu elemento, caso seja ele terá position fixed, e caso não seja ele voltará para position absolute. Não cheguei a testar, da uma conferida ai

Comment: Essa função não funcionou muito bem. Quando eu dou scrolldow, o objeto fica travando entre o topo e a parte de baixo.

Comment: Ao definir o `position:fixed` você pode definir onde você quer que o elemento fique usando como por exemplo `top:0` vai travar o elemento no topo, se você deixar ele fixo em não definir uma posição o mesmo deve tender a bugar mesmo usando essa função

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) para isso. Quando atingir a largura de 700px e altura de 600px, a posição vai mudar de absoluta para fixa. Você pode definir as outras propriedades nela também. Tudo o que você definir dentro desse escopo será aplicado quando diminuir a tela.

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px), screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  div#retangulo{
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
```

```css
header{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background-color:#423142;
}

div#retangulo{
  width:50px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: green;
  position:absolute;
  top:220px;
  left:100px;
}

footer{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top: 1500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px), screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  div#retangulo{
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="retangulo">
  {texto exemplo....}
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Veja funcionando no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhzscLzu/).

Comment: Não entendi o porquê de ser `max-width:700px` e `max-height:600px`

Comment: Esse é o tamanho da tela, você decide a altura e a largura que quiser. Foi só uma sugestão.

Comment: Mas é que, desse modo, sempre ficará `position:fixed;`

Comment: Sim, sempre que a tela estiver no tamanho que você definir na media, o CSS será o definido dentro dela.